# Customize bootstrap classes in Angular development

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4 and sass in my angular 6 application development.

I am trying to make a nav tab in my application by customizing bootstrap nav-tabs, nav-link class slightly. However, customized bootstrap class is not reflecting. So, my question is can we customize bootstrap class in our angular application development? If so, how can we do it? Below is my code snippet of my angular component.

myComponent.html:

```
<div class="profile-head">
    <h5>
       Sreehari
    </h5>
    <h6>
       Developer
    </h6>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">About</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Updated: My main problem is, when I click on the "About and Profile" tabs, the blue border-bottom should move to the active tab. However, its not moving at all.

myComponent.scss:

```
.profile-head {
h5 {
    color: #333;
}

h6{
    color: #0062cc;
}

p{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #818182;
    margin-top: 5%;
    span{
        color: #495057;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }
}

.nav-tabs{
    margin-bottom:5%;

    .nav-link{
        font-weight:600;
        border: none;
        &.active{                
            border: none;
            border-bottom:2px solid #0062cc;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have imported bootstrap in my styles.scss as below.

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style are already good imported. But you can not switch between the `active` statement because bootstrap need `Jquery` and `bootstrap.js` to switch the classes.

In order to make a routing with active statement in angular for your tabs. Either use `Jquery` and `BootstrapJs` in your project (**not recommended**) or build your logic in your `component.ts` here is a example how you can do this: [Routable twitter bootstrap tabs made with Angular](https://medium.com/@golbie/routable-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-made-with-angular-2-b2272dd2c319)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. I have create project using ng cli. I dont have any file like main.scss. I have a global styles.scss which was created by ng cli. So, I have imported bootstrap module over there. Could you elaborate your answer?